# Llamada asíncrona con firebase y angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

En mi código hago una petición a la url que me proporciona `firebase` para conectar con los datos para autentificar el usuario.

Tengo este controller:

**CONTROLLER**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ["userService", "$scope", "serviceMens" , function (userService, $scope, serviceMens) {
$scope.user = {};

$scope.loginUserDate = function(){
    var result;
    userService.login($scope.user)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(error){
        //console.log(error.code);
        result = error.code;
        if(result === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            serviceMens.show_error('La contraseña es incorrecta');
        }else if(result === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            serviceMens.show_error('Este usuario no existe');
        }else if(result === 'auth/too-many-requests'){
            serviceMens.show_error('Hemos bloqueado todas las peticiones de este dispositivo debido a la actividad inusual. Inténtelo de nuevo más tarde.');
        }
    });
}
}]);
```

Cuando el usuario introduce su email y contraseña pulsa el botón de entrar que activa $scope.loginUserDate, este hace la petición correctamente. 
El problema llega cuando los datos son incorrectos, entonces se me devuelve un resultado que yo controlo con IF, estas condicionales funcionan correctamente, pero para que me muestre el mensaje de error en la vista tengo que clickear en el input o en el botón.

**SERVICES**

```
.factory('userService', [function () {

var ref = firebase.auth();

var service = {
    login: function(user){

        return ref.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    },
    user: {}

}
return service; }]);
```

**VISTA**

```
<div ng-show="flash_error">{{flash_error}}</div>
```

**serviceMens**

```
.factory('serviceMens', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
return {
  show_success : function(message){
      $rootScope.flash_success = message;
  },
  show_error : function(message){
      $rootScope.flash_error = message;
  },
  clear : function(){
      $rootScope.flash_success = "";
      $rootScope.flash_error = "";
  }
}}]);
```

Comment: podrías poner el codigo del `serviceMens`?

Comment: Ya esta añadido!

Comment: nota al margen, no uses mensajes diferentes para clave incorrecta y el usuario no existe, permite detectar nombres de usuario validos. Lo cual resuelve la mitad del problema para un atacante. utiliza un solo mensaje de "usuario o contraseña inválidos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que estás modificando el $rootScope de forma asincrona, necesitas de alguna forma indicarle al hilo de ejecución que tu scope cambiará en "un futuro". Para esto, angular nos provee de la función `$apply`, de forma tal que cualquier `watcher` sea notificado del cambio.

En el siguiente snippet, tomé un poco de tu código, lo simplifiqué y apliqué un `timeout` para imitar la asincronicidad:

```js
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('LoginCtrl', ["$scope", "serviceMens" , function ($scope, serviceMens) {

$scope.loginUserDate = function(){
  var msg = 'La contraseña es incorrecta: ' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 10);
  console.log("showing " + msg)
  setTimeout(function(){
    serviceMens.show_error(msg);  
  }, 1000);
  
}
}]);

app.factory('serviceMens', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
return {
  show_error : function(message){
    // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
      $rootScope.flash_error = message;  
    })
    
  }
}}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
      <button ng-click="loginUserDate()">click me!</button>
      <h1 ng-show="flash_error">{{flash_error}}</h1> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Recomiendo leer [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Si, la verdad es que me sirvió. Tengo que aprender más del funcionamiento de angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Así es como quedaría mi código:

```
app.factory('serviceMens', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
return {
  show_success : function(message){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
      $rootScope.flash_success = message;
    });
  },
  show_error : function(message){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
      $rootScope.flash_error = message;
    });
  },
  clear : function(){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
      $rootScope.flash_success = "";
      $rootScope.flash_error = "";
    });
  }
}}]);
```

Desconozco si es mejorable.